# Adding a AJAX response data to a store

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

How to add a data to a json store if my data is coming from a back end AJAX call.

my store is as follows .

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.GeographyMasterStore', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


requires: [
    'MyApp.model.GeographyMasterModel'
],


config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.GeographyMasterModel',
    storeId: 'geographyMasterStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
});
```

And my model is as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.GeographyMasterModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',


config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'Code'
        },
        {
            name: 'Description'
        },
        {
            name: 'Level_Code',
            mapping: 'Level Code'
        },
        {
            name: 'Name'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

If I add the data like this

```
var geographyMasterStore = Ext.getStore('geographyMasterStore');
geographyMasterStore.add(<data from backend AJAX call>);
```

it does not show me the mapped field i.e. Level_Code

Answer (score 0):

Usually I when add a record to the store like this :

```
Ext.create('App.model.MyModel', JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

Where response is the response from an `Ext.Ajax.request`

Hope this helps

Comment: how can i add the data like this to a store , i have a store predefined and a model also, here you are creating a new model.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a model:

`var record = Ext.create('model.GeographyMasterModel', Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText));`

save the model:

`record.save()`

reload the store:

`geographyMasterStore.load()`

Comment: it does not allow me to create a model with above code. it gives the following error.

Comment: My concern here is that i am not getting the field Level_Code which is mapped to the Level Code field. you can see that in model code.